# Why is ip forwarding not working in xubuntu 14?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, firewall

I upgraded my gateway computer from xubuntu 12 to 14 and the computers on my home network lost their internet connection. I found that the upgrade had uninstalled my old firewall, Firestarter, and replaced it with ufw. My efforts to get this working have had no success but what really bothers me is that even with the firewall disabled the clients (my children's computers) still cannot reach the internet. I have done the recommended edits in /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf and when I run `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` I get `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`. The hosts and the gateway can ping each other okay but the hosts cannot ping the internet, eg google or 8.8.8.8. The gateway can access the internet but not the hosts. This has worked fine for years until the upgrade. Why is the ip forwarding not working?

Just in case ufw had some default configuration that was preventing ip forwarding I took the drastic step of uninstalling Gufw and ufw. Still no internet access for the host computers. I found another sysctl.conf in /etc and uncommented the line, net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 then ran `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` and got the response, `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`. But it's still not working. The hosts can ping the gateway but they cannot reach the internet.

I am not the geeky type who digs about in man pages for fun, but I've had a go. Here is the output from `sudo ufw status verbose` (My home network is on 192.168.0.0/24):

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
192.168.0.2                ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24
22                         LIMIT IN    Anywhere
Anywhere on eth0           ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24
22 (v6)                    LIMIT IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Does this look okay?

But even if it is good, the real problem, I think, is that the host computers cannot reach the internet. The gateway computer can. Disabling the firewall makes no difference: the host computers can ping the gateway and ssh to the gateway, but they cannot ping an internet site such as **8.8.8.8**.

I set up this home network about 7 years ago on Debian then moved to xubuntu lts. Its been really good and I've never had to touch it. I know a lot has changed since then in the system config files so I could really use some help as I use this network for work and children's homework, not as a hobby.
Following ubuntu's own documentation here, https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html#other-firewall-tools, I tried editing /etc/ufw/before.rules: I added these lines:

```
# nat Table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from eth1 through eth0.
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However when I restarted the firewall I got this error message:

```
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
Bad argument `*filter'
Error occurred at line: 22
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'

(I didn't touch line 22!) I restored the file to its original state and the firewall started up okay. I cannot think of anything else to try. Has anybody got any ideas?

I solved the problem by adding the line `COMMIT` after the line
`-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`. I thought it was not required because `COMMIT` appears at the end of the file. But that made it work.